# Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS + HOSTAPD

Tags: server, settings, hostapd

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS with the latest kernel as well as Hostapd v2.1, and can not make a point of working here logs hostad. Please help solve the problem!

```
administrator@ubuntu-server:/$ sudo hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not add multicast membership for vendor events: -2 (No such file or directory)
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 4 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x8604d50
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 nl_handle=0x8604d50 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=176): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=4)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x86036f0)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x86036f0)
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x86042f8 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x86036f0)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x86042f8
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x86036f0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x86036f0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x86036f0
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running your command (`sudo hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`), run follow command

```
sudo nmcli nm wifi off
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

Or downgrade hostapd to version 1.

Comment: On ubuntu server no application nmcli rfkill. Yes, I downgrade to hostapd v.1. But now I get the error:Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-4)
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
rmdir[ctrl_interface]: No such file or directory
nl80211: Remove interface ifindex=9
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=0, operstate=6
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 6 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 6 to mode 2: -16 (Device or resource busy)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down